# Sed a file to include `pwd`

Tags: sed

I'm not able to figure this one out. In a file called docker-compose.yaml I want to substitute ROSPERSISTENT-PATH with the result of `pwd` + "/rospersistent" which seems like a job for sed. But I am getting tripped up by quotes.

I've tried this (and many permutations of this):

```
sed "s/ROSPERSISTENT-PATH/$(pwd)/" docker-compose.yaml
```

Can someone tell me where I am missing the boat? Thanks!

Comment: What other variants have you tried, and what were their results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you most likely have the forward slash `/` in the output of `$(pwd)`, this will interfere with the forward slashes sed uses to separate the search pattern and replacement.
The best 'workaround' is to substitute the forward slash with a character which is not present in the search pattern nor in the replacement. (e.g. | )

```
sed "s|ROSPERSISTENT-PATH|$(pwd)/rospersistent|" docker-compose.yaml
```